# How to show that $ n^{2} = 4^{{\log_{2}}(n)} $?

Tags: functions

I ran across this simple identity yesterday, but can’t seem to find a way to get from one side to the other:
$$
n^{2} = 4^{{\log_{2}}(n)}.
$$

Wolfram Alpha tells me that it is true, but other than that, I’m stuck.

Comment: By the way, in mathematics you just use "$=$", not "$==$", to say that two things are equal. It's called the *equals sign* after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that
$$a^{\log_a(x)} = x \,\,\,\,\,\, \forall a,x >0$$
Hence, $$4^{\log_2(n)} = (2^{2})^{\log_2(n)} = (2^{\log_2(n)})^2 = n^2$$

Comment: Oh I'm an idiot, I forgot that apart from $(2^m)^n == 2^{m*n}$ we could also swap the m and n.. obvious now that someone tells me.

Answer (score 5):

$$4^{\log_2n}=\left(2^2\right)^{\log_2n}=2^{2\log_2n}=\left(2^{\log_2n}\right)^2=n^2$$

Comment: The outside exponent in the second to last term should be a $2$, not an $n$.

Comment: @Aaron: Eep! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\log_{2}$ of both sides and get
$$n^{2} = 4^{{\log_{2}} n}$$
$$2\log_{2}n =2\log_{2}n $$

Comment: This is the natural way taught in high school for such questions. (Sister)

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=2^t$ then for LHS we have : $n^2=(2^t)^2=2^{2t}$

and for RHS : $4^{Log_2 n}=4^{Log_2 2^t}=4^t=(2^2)^t=2^{2t}$

LHS = RHS $\square$